# Simple way of finding the locus of $z$?

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-geometry

I am tasked to sketch the locus of complex numbers $z$ that satisfies
$$(z-2+i)^2 + (z^*-2-i)^2 + 2zz^* + 6 = 0$$
I was wondering if there’s a special trick to this question, or if this is only solvable by plugging in $z=x+iy$ ?

I noticed that the second term is the conjugate of the first, and wanted to substitute $w = z-2+i$, however this gives me a complicated expression for $zz^*$ which makes it more confusing. Is there a trick I’m missing out? Thanks!

**Edit:** I have already solved it through direct substitution (parabola intersecting real axis at $x=3$ and $x=-1$) but it took a good 5 minutes or so, expanding everything correctly, which seems rather long (I was attempting it under exam conditions). I was just wondering if it is possible to exploit the $w$ substitution I made in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $z=x+yi$

The expression turns into $$[(x-2)+i(y+1)]^2+[(x-2)-i(y+1)]^2+2(x^2+y^2)+6$$
$$=2(x^2-4x+4)-2(y^2+2y+1)+2(x^2+y^2)+6$$

Which simply turns out to be $$4x^2-8x+12-4y=0$$
$$\Rightarrow y=x^2-2x+3$$

Which is clearly a parabola

Answer (score 1):

You *know* the answer is quadratic in $x$ and $y$. Can you quickly figure out the coefficients of $x^2$ and $y^2$? Once you do, you'll realize that the locus has a pretty simple form.

That being said: in general, there's no quick and easy method for doing problems like this, and just multiplying out and then completing the square may be your best bet as a general skill.

Comment: Ah, yes, the final result is rather beautiful, just a shame the expansion’s so messy!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Note that

$$(z-2+i)^2 + (z^*-2-i)^2 + 2zz^* + 6 = 0\iff (z+\bar z)^2-4(z+\bar z)+2i(z-\bar z)+12=0$$

then use

- $z+\bar z=2\,\Re(z)$
- $z-\bar z=2i\,\Im(z)$

Comment: Hello, how did you notice this so quickly, or did you multiply out $z$ and $\bar{z}$?

Comment: yes I've just multiplied out, it is not so difficult, more over you can take $a=-2+i$ and observe that the expression is in the form $(z+a)^2+(\bar z + \bar z)^2+2z\bar z+6=0$